# Problems with soap UI

Tags: soapui

I consume REST service in SOAP UI and run good in local machine, but i try run the same REST service but in remote desktop and not running and in get 
"
Fri Apr 12 12:39:25 GMT-03:00 2019:INFO:Error getting response for [https://api.mercadopago.com.Preferences:Request 1]; org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.mercadopago.com refused
".

Comment: Sounds like the remote machine does not have access to your target.

Comment: do a curl or other http request from the remote machine to the API machine. As @siking says it looks like a connectivity issue.